# .Net Core: Unable to Scaffold Identity from Data Access Layer Context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am working on a small .net core 3.1 application for learning purposes, I have one Razor Pages Project used as presentation layer (UI), one link library for Domain and One for Data Access along with a Link Library for Business Layer.

I am trying to integrate the Core Identity in DAL, I have successfully created tables etc., but I cannot scaffold Identity using DB Context from my Data Access Layer, my db context looks as following:

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=DESKTOP-9CTCUHB;
                                    Database= xyz;
                                    Integrated Security= True");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Business>()
            .HasOne(e => e.BusinessProfile)
            .WithOne(b => b.Business)
            .HasForeignKey<BusinessProfile>(e => e.BusinessId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Business>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Bookings)
            .WithOne(b => b.Business)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BusinessID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Business>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Serivces)
            .WithOne(b => b.Business)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BusinessID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
            

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Business)
            .WithOne(b => b.BusinessOwnerUser)
            .HasForeignKey<Business>(b => b.BusinessOwnerUserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Business>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Type)
            .WithOne(b => b.Business)
            .HasForeignKey<BusinessType>(e => e.BusinessID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Business>()
            .HasOne(e => e.BusinessOwnerUser)
            .WithOne(b => b.Business)
            .HasForeignKey<AppUser>(e => e.BusinessID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
             .HasMany(e => e.ServiceBooking)
             .WithOne(b => b.Booking)
             .HasForeignKey( e  => e.BookingID)
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ServiceBooking)
            .WithOne(b => b.Service)
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.ServiceID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentInfo>()
            .HasOne(e => e.PaymentMethod)
            .WithOne(b => b.Payment)
            .HasForeignKey<PaymentMethod>(e => e.PaymendInfoID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

My startup for RazorUI looks like

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

   
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MLContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MLContext>();
    }

   
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

I am using the MLContext to scaffold Core Identity, but getting the following error:

[image]

I have tried almost every solution related to mismatching packages etc, I believe it has something to do with DbContext.

Any help would be awesome and thank you in advance.

Comment: Try scaffolding DbContext in the web project, then move the classes to data access layer.

Comment: Same error, but thank you for help.

Comment: Can you scaffold using from the terminal?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli. Run it with `--verbose` flag to see what's actually preventing the process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the NuGet Cache. To do this ->

-> Go to Tools
-> Options
-> NuGet Package Manager
-> General
-> Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

If not work then check your all Nuget package and make sure your NuGet package version is similar to your .net core. for example:- you are using .net core 3.1 so your all NuGet package manager version should be 3.0/3.1/3.2 like that. version.especially check`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`NuGet package version, check it is similar to your .net core version or not.`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` this package should version is 3.0/3.1. if not then upgrade or downgrade your version. after that clear again the nuget cache hope it worked.